# Suggestion for creating custom sound recognition software to toggle audio

Tags: audio, voice-recognition

I need to develop a program that toggles a particular audio track on or off when it recognizes a parrot scream or screech. The software would need to recognize a particular range of sounds and allow some variations in the range (as a parrot likely won't replicate its sreeches EXACTLY each time).

**Example:** Bird screeches, no audio. Bird stops screeching for five seconds, audio track praising the bird plays. Regular chattering needs to be ignored completely, as it is not to be discouraged.

I've heard of java libraries that have speech recognition with dictionaries built in, but the software would need to be taught the particular sounds that my particular parrot makes - not words or any random bird sound. In addition as I mentioned above, it would need to allow for slight variation in the sound, as the screech will likely never be 100% identical to the recorded version.

What would be the best way to go about this/what language should I look into?

**Edit:** Alternatively (and perhaps this would be a more simple solution), is there a way to make the audio toggle based on the volume of input? So it wouldn't matter what kind of sound the parrot makes, just how loud it is?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be tightly related to voice recognition. I would recomend taking a look at this post: [How to convert human voice into digital format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131685/how-to-convert-human-voice-into-digital-format/)